# Some NSDate questions considering locale settings etc

Tags: ios, localization, nsdate

I'm still kind of new to iOS and struggling a bit with NSDate. Basically I have certain CostPeriods in my app:

```
CostPeriodDaily
CostPeriodWeekly
CostPeriodMonthly
CostPeriodSemiAnnually
CostPeriodAnnually
```

Depending on the CostPeriod I want the start and end date for that certain period. CostPeriodDaily would of course be from (i.e. today) 16.Feb 2014 00:00:00 (local time) - 16.Feb 2014 23:59:59 (local time). Monthly would be from 01.Feb 2014 00:00:00 - 28.Feb 2014 23:59:59 etc.

I have two specific questions first:

1. NSWeekdayCalendarUnit: Is 1 ALWAYS Sunday and 7 Saturday? No matter
   what locale is set?
2. If I NSLog my endDate (as in the following code) or start date it usually is the date and 23:00:00 since I'm living in the time zone
   GMT+1. Is this correct?

And now to my endDate function, two further questions :-)

- Is this function in general ok or will I run in some problems depending on specific locale settings?
- My CostPeriodWeekly case gives me the wrong date 2014-02-15 23:00:00 +0000 for today. I don't know why...?

+(NSDate *)endDateForCurrentCostPeriod:(CostPeriod)costPeriod{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

```
NSDateComponents *todayComponents =
[gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSRange daysOfCurrentMonth = [gregorian rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];


NSDateComponents *endDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

switch (costPeriod) {
    case CostPeriodDaily:
        [endDateComponents setDay:[todayComponents day]];
        [endDateComponents setMonth:[todayComponents month]];
        [endDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];
        break;

    case CostPeriodWeekly:
        //Weekday 1 = sunday, 2 = monday
        if([todayComponents weekday] == 1){
            //Sunday -> do nothing, we have the end date
            [endDateComponents setDay:[todayComponents day]];
            [endDateComponents setMonth:[todayComponents month]];
            [endDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];

        } else {
            // all other days of current week, so 8- weekday (if Friday: 8 - 6 = + 2 -> Sunday)
            NSDateComponents *componentsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            [componentsToAdd setDay: 8 - [todayComponents weekday]];
            NSDate *endOfWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToAdd
                                                                 toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

            NSDateComponents *endOfWeekComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:endOfWeek];

            [endDateComponents setDay:[endOfWeekComponents day]];
            [endDateComponents setMonth:[endOfWeekComponents month]];
            [endDateComponents setYear:[endOfWeekComponents year]];
        }
        break;

    case CostPeriodMonthly:
        [endDateComponents setDay:daysOfCurrentMonth.length];
        [endDateComponents setMonth:[todayComponents month]];
        [endDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];
        break;

    case CostPeriodSemiAnnually:
        [endDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];

        if([todayComponents month] <= 6){
            [endDateComponents setDay:30];
            [endDateComponents setMonth:6];
        } else {
            [endDateComponents setDay:31];
            [endDateComponents setMonth:12];
        }
        break;

    case CostPeriodAnnually:
        [endDateComponents setDay:31];
        [endDateComponents setMonth:12];
        [endDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];
        break;

    default:
        [endDateComponents setDay:daysOfCurrentMonth.length];
        [endDateComponents setMonth:[todayComponents month]];
        [endDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];
        break;
}

NSDate *endDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:endDateComponents];
return endDate;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NSWeekdayCalendarUnit: Is 1 ALWAYS Sunday and 7 Saturday? No matter what locale is set?

That is correct. But that does not mean that 1=Sunday is always considered to be the first day in the week. `NSCalendar` has a `firstWeekDay` method, and *that*
is locale dependent. (For example, in Germany *Monday* is the first day of the week.)

> If I NSLog my endDate (as in the following code) or start date it
>   usually is the date and 23:00:00 since I'm living in the time zone
>   GMT+1. Is this correct?

That is correct.

> Is this function in general ok or will I run in some problems
>   depending on specific locale settings?

Your method looks overly complicated. To determine a period you can use

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *startOfPeriod, *endOfPeriod;
NSTimeInterval lengthOfPeriod;

NSCalendarUnit unit = NSDayCalendarUnit; // or NSWeekCalendarUnit, NSMonthCalendarUnit, ...
[cal rangeOfUnit:unit startDate:&startOfPeriod interval:&lengthOfPeriod forDate:now];
endOfPeriod = [startOfPeriod dateByAddingTimeInterval:lengthOfPeriod]
```

That should work correctly according to your locale. For the current week of today
(Sunday, Feb 16) in Germany that would give the results

```
startOfPeriod =  2014-02-10 00:00:00 CET
endOfPeriod   =  2014-02-17 00:00:00 CET
```

because the week starts on a Monday here. (So actually `endOfPeriod` is not the end
of the period, but the start of the following period.)

For the **semi-annual period**
there is no corresponding `NSCalendarUnit`, so you could proceed as follows:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Compute start and end of the current year (as above):
NSDate *startOfYear, *endOfYear;
NSTimeInterval lengthOfYear;
NSCalendarUnit unit = NSYearCalendarUnit;
[cal rangeOfUnit:unit startDate:&startOfYear interval:&lengthOfYear forDate:now];
endOfYear = [startOfYear dateByAddingTimeInterval:lengthOfYear];

// Compute middle of the year:
NSDateComponents *halfYear = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSRange range = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit forDate:now];
halfYear.month = range.length/2;
NSDate *middleOfYear = [cal dateByAddingComponents:halfYear toDate:startOfYear options:0];

// Compare current date with middle of the year and set start/end of period:
NSDate *startOfPeriod, *endOfPeriod;
if ([now compare:middleOfYear] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    startOfPeriod = startOfYear;
    endOfPeriod = middleOfYear;
} else {
    startOfPeriod = middleOfYear;
    endOfPeriod = endOfYear;
}
```

**EDIT: Changed everything with the help from Martin to this. Works, but still confused about the end date +1day +1 hour necessity...**

```
+ (NSDate *)startDateForCostPeriod:(CostPeriod)costPeriod withDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *startOfPeriod;
    NSTimeInterval lengthOfPeriod;
    //If unit is not initialized here, semi annual throws always a caution message since no unit is initialized there
    NSCalendarUnit unit = NSMonthCalendarUnit;

    //For the SemiAnnual period we need date components
    NSDateComponents *todayComponents =
    [calender components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit ) fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *startDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    switch (costPeriod) {
        case CostPeriodDaily:
            unit = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            break;

        case CostPeriodWeekly:
            unit = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
            break;

        case CostPeriodMonthly:
            unit = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
            break;

        case CostPeriodSemiAnnually:
            [startDateComponents setDay:1];
            [startDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];

            if([todayComponents month] <= 6){
                [startDateComponents setMonth:1];
            } else {
                [startDateComponents setMonth:7];
            }
            break;

        case CostPeriodAnnually:
            unit = NSYearCalendarUnit;
            break;

        default:
            unit = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
            break;
    }

    if(costPeriod != CostPeriodSemiAnnually){
        [calender rangeOfUnit:unit startDate:&startOfPeriod interval:&lengthOfPeriod forDate:date];
        return startOfPeriod;
    } else {
        return [calender dateFromComponents:startDateComponents];
    }
}

+ (NSDate *)endDateForCostPeriod:(CostPeriod)costPeriod withDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *startOfPeriod;
    NSTimeInterval lengthOfPeriod;
    //If unit is not initialized here, semi annual throws always a caution message since no unit is initialized there
    NSCalendarUnit unit = NSMonthCalendarUnit;

    //For the SemiAnnual period we need date components
    NSDateComponents *todayComponents =
    [calender components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit ) fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *endDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    switch (costPeriod) {
        case CostPeriodDaily:
            unit = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            break;

        case CostPeriodWeekly:
            unit = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
            break;

        case CostPeriodMonthly:
            unit = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
            break;

        case CostPeriodSemiAnnually:
            [endDateComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];

            if([todayComponents month] <= 6){
                [endDateComponents setDay:30];
                [endDateComponents setMonth:6];
            } else {
                [endDateComponents setDay:31];
                [endDateComponents setMonth:12];
            }
            break;

        case CostPeriodAnnually:
            unit = NSYearCalendarUnit;
            break;

        default:
            unit = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
            break;
    }

    if(costPeriod != CostPeriodSemiAnnually){
        [calender rangeOfUnit:unit startDate:&startOfPeriod interval:&lengthOfPeriod forDate:date];
        return [startOfPeriod dateByAddingTimeInterval:lengthOfPeriod];
    } else {
        //somehow if you take the date without a time it is always 1 day and 1 hour before. i.e. 16.2.2014 is 15.2.2014 22:00:00
        //thats why you need to add 1 day and 1 hour!
        NSDate *endDate = [calender dateFromComponents:endDateComponents];
        NSDateComponents *componentsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [componentsToAdd setDay: 1];
        [componentsToAdd setHour: 1];
        endDate = [calender dateByAddingComponents:componentsToAdd
                                             toDate:endDate options:0];

        return endDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. If I understand correctly this method of yours works for every locale, no matter if Monday or Sunday is the first day of the week, no matter what timezone etc.? And could you maybe show me how you get the startDate of a period as well with this approach please?

Comment: @MichiZH: The start date is already computed with that code. It is a bit "hidden" in the `startDate:&startOfPeriod` argument. And yes, that should give the correct result according to your locale and time zone.

Comment: Thanks alot once again. Will try that now in my app :-) Always happy to learn something :-)

Comment: one more question: What unit and lengthOfPeriod would you use for the half year period?

Comment: @MichiZH: There is no calendar unit for a half year period. For that case you have to compute it using `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: Ok got it all working except the semi year. I don't know how you would do that with NSDateComponents and this rangeOfUnit? Do you have an example? And one more question: The interval variable returns a value relative to which date? Or what exactly represents this interval?

Comment: @MichiZH: The interval variable is set to the length of the period (in seconds). The end date is computed by adding this length to the start date. - You already have code for the semi-year period. Does that give the correct results? - I don't know if that can be done much better. If I find something then I will update the answer ...

Comment: Ah you mean using completely my code for the semi year? I'll try that but don't know if that accounts for all the locale stuff. Thanks for all your efforts. So since the enddate is already the start of the new period, my predicates for core data look now all like this: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND date < %@", startDate, endDate]];

Comment: @MichiZH: I have added some code for the semi-annual period. And you are completely right about the predicate.

Comment: Sorry somehow placed my edit in your post, but makes probably sense in this case. Can remove it if you don't like it. I've tried to use my semi annual calculation first (since I've edited already everything) :-) But still confused why I have to add 1 day and 1 hour to my end date? Does this work for all locales?